# How to limit UI installation paths in WIX?

Tags: wix, installation

I am writing an installation script using WIX and have a question that arises in regards to the user selected location for installation. The program that needs to be installed needs to be installed at the root drive C:/, D:/, ext for the program to work. Using the Wix UI package WIXUI_INSTALLDIR the user can change the path that the program is installed too what I want to do is to make it impossible for the user to change anything except the root drive ie change D:\usr\sparrow\bin ---> C:\usr\sparrow bin if they so desired. Does anyone have any suggestions about how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a custom action and a custom dialog, but I wouldn't do this. It is a lot of work, and doesn't seem to have any major benefits.

If I were you I would remove the chance to install to a custom location altogether. However, if the setup is run by command line, you won't be able to control what path they specify for TARGETDIR / INSTALLDIR anyway, unless you add a custom action check to abort the setup if the path is not to be allowed:

```
msiexec /i setup.msi TARGETDIR=c:\anypathcanbewrittenhere
```

Comment: Yea I originally was using the WIXUI_minimal to keep the user from installing the program anywhere other than the root drive however if you needed to accomplish this using a custom action what would you do?

Comment: Directories get resolved during FileCosting or thereabouts. I would write a custom action and insert it just before InstallInitialize. This should inspect the INSTALLDIR / TARGETDIR and reject it if unsuitable. Then write into the installer log with information. I don't have a sample for you at hand just now.